# Can't debug invalid large JSON array

Tags: json

I have a large JSON file of array objects - 7510 lines.

I am trying to find out where the file is invalid using json lint pro. I keep getting the error in the image below but I can't find what the problem is:

[image: parse error]

These are the last 3 objects at the end of my file starting, ending on line 7509 - which the json lint appears to be referring to. I can't see anything obvious here but I've been looking at it for a long time!:

```
[...
        {
          "id": "111707",
          "name": "Seven Park Place by William Drabble",
          "phone": "+442073161600",
          "email": "restaurant@stjameshotelandclub.com",
          "website": "http://www.stjameshotelandclub.com/michelin-star-chef-william-drabble",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.5062548,
            "longitude": -0.1403209,
            "address": {
              "line1": "7-8 Park Place",
              "line2": "St James's",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "SW1A 1LP",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "104493",
          "name": "Seymour's Restaurant & Bar",
          "phone": "+442079352010",
          "email": "reservations@theleonard.com",
          "website": "http://www.theleonard.com",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.51463,
            "longitude": -0.15779,
            "address": {
              "line1": "15 Seymour Street",
              "line2": "",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "W1H 7JW",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "250922",
          "name": "Shaka Zulu",
          "phone": "+442033769911",
          "email": "info@shaka-zulu.com",
          "website": "http://www.shaka-zulu.com/",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.5414979,
            "longitude": -0.1458655,
            "address": {
              "line1": "Stables Market ",
              "line2": "Camden",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "NW1 8AB",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        }
    ]
```

When I run the file in terminal (just to get the length of how many objects), I get this "unexpected token" error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 399: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from length.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What you posted here is valid JSON. Try to send us a whole file, e.g. you can upload it in pastebin.

Comment: sure its here: http://pastebin.com/5QcPmAvS